# Best way to scale scala + akka microservices?

Tags: scala, akka, microservices, akka-http

We are planning to create few new microservices as part of our platform.

Currently all our microservices are Java-Spring based, and we use docker/kubernetes to scale.

We are now planning to evaluate Scala-Akka to create microservice.

Any pointers about how we can scale Scala-Akka microservice will be great help. 
We found that (in some blogs) than scala-akka microservice are also being deployed as docker containers. Is that the only way to scale scala-akka services or is there any other possible way as well?

Also, akka provides components which can help in scaling, as mentioned in following blog:
https://www.datio.com/iaas/building-a-docker-container-orchestrator-with-akka/

Which is better way to scale scala-akka microservices?

Thanks

Anuj

Comment: The way to scale a microservice is deploy another instance. Language it is written in doesn't matter. Whether you use docker to deploy it or something else is also irrelevant.

Comment: not necessarily. Docker is not the only way possible. Refer to article blow: https://www.datio.com/iaas/building-a-docker-container-orchestrator-with-akka/      Scala provides inbuilt components which can be used to scale without using docker. Wanted to have a discussion around which is preferred way of scaling.

Comment: That's what I said. There are many possible ways to deploy a service. Which one you pick is largely a matter of taste and doesn't matter for anything.

Comment: have rephrased my question. I was looking for opinions around preferred way to scale scala-akka microservice.

Comment: The way to scale any microservice is deploy another instance

Answer (score 2):

Akka has akka-management which provides 2 ways to deploy/discovery the service by kubernetes: By DNS and Kube APIs.

It really works.

```
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/discovery/kubernetes.html
```